# W-shaped Event Vol and Butterfly Arbitrage

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, quant-trading-strategies, arbitrage, quants

I came across the Vola Dynamics page about the W-shaped vol before an event: https://voladynamics.com/marketEquityUS_AMZN.html

I'm a bit confused by "this term does not have any butterfly arbitrage". I thought butterfly arbitrage suggests that price against strike is convex, i.e., $\partial^2 C/\partial K^2 > 0$. But the W-shape around the forward is clearly not convex.

I guess it may be because the y-axis is not price but vol, but then I thought roughly as vol is higher the price is higher too.

Any formula to check the butterfly arbitrage in the vol space? I mean, with some rule to check including for example $\partial \sigma^2 / \partial K^2$.

Comment: Hint: $C(K) = C^{BS}(K,IV(K))$. Differentiate both sides twice wrt to $K$ and then find the equivalent condition on IVs for no butterfly arbitrage.

Comment: @Frido, Thanks. I found the answer in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0646.pdf

Comment: Yes, so in that paper equation 2.1 is I think what you're looking for, i.e $g(k) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the call option price $C$ as a function of strike $K$ and (strike-)implied volatility $\sigma(K)$, we have $C(K,\sigma(K))$. No-arbitrage requires the total derivative of the call option price w.r.t. the strike to be $\geq 0$, i.e.:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2C}{\mathrm{d}K^2}&\geq 0\\
 \Rightarrow \quad\quad 0&\leq\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial K^2}+2\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial K\partial\sigma }\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial K}+\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial\sigma^2 }\left(\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial K}\right)^2+\frac{\partial C}{\partial\sigma }\frac{\partial ^2\sigma}{\partial K^2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Local volatility (LV) must be positive. The expression for LV in vol space can be found [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=4f135a80c3b17bb838d6dde7873ecc58c69aa6bd) on page 10.